# Compare directories and delete files using Diff

Tags: bash, diff

I have this diff command that compares folders recursively

```
diff -rq /var/www/dir/ ~/temp/dir/ >> files-to-delete.txt
```

It outputs lines line this

```
Only in /var/www/staging.newnaturalists.com/htdocs/wp-content/themes/newnats: base.php
```

What I would like is to be able to delete the files that are not in the second location, basically deleting files that are outputted in the txt file

Is there a simple way to do that (I don't need the txt file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use awk in combination with your `diff` command :

```
rm $(diff -rq /var/www/dir/ ~/temp/dir/ | awk '/Only in \/var\/www\/dir/{print substr($3, 1, length($3)-1) "/" $4}')
```

Comment: Excellent, just what I needed